# function that merges two singly linked lists to form a third one

Tags: c++, list, merge

So i am writing a programm where user fills two linked lists with integers, and now i need to create a function that creates third linked list with values from both first and second lists without duplicates. 
Here is the code i have right now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int info;
    node *next;
    node (int i, node *n=NULL)
    {
        info = i;
        next = n;
    }
    ~node() 
    {
        cout <<"NODE CONTAINING \"" << info << "\" WAS DELETED!" << endl;
    }
};
struct list
{
    node* startList1, *lastList1, *startList2, *lastList2;
    int menuOption;
    int nodeCount1=0, nodeCount2=0; 


    list() {
        startList1 = NULL;
        startList2 = NULL;

    }


    void addList1(node *p)
    {
        int n;
        cout << "PLEASE INPUT VALUE WHICH YOU WANT IN THE NODE:";
        cin >> n;
        p = new node(n);
        nodeCount1++;
        if(startList1==NULL)
        {
            startList1 = lastList1 = p;
        }
        else
        {
            lastList1->next = p;
            lastList1 = p;
        }
    }

    void printList1(node *pr)
    {
        node *pr;
        for (pr=startList1; pr!=NULL; pr=pr->next)
        {
            cout << pr->info << endl;
        }
    }



    void addList2(node *q)
    {
        int n;
        cout << "PLEASE INPUT VALUE WHICH YOU WANT IN THE NODE:";
        cin >> n;
        q = new node(n);
        nodeCount2++;
        if(startList2==NULL)
        {
            startList2 = lastList2 = q;
        }
        else
        {
            lastList2->next = q;
            lastList2 = q;
        }
    }
    void printList2(node *pr)
    {
        for (pr=startList2; pr!=NULL; pr=pr->next)
        {
            cout << pr->info << endl;
        }
    }

   // this just prints first and second lists to show what is inside..
    void printBoth(node *pr, node *qr)
    {
        cout << "Elements of the first list:" << endl;
        for (pr=startList1; pr!=NULL; pr=pr->next)
        {
            cout << pr->info << endl;
        }
        cout << "Elements of the second list:" << endl;
        for (pr=startList2; pr!=NULL; pr=pr->next)
        {
            cout << pr->info << endl;
        }
    }


    void printMenu()
    {
        cout << "MENU" << endl;
        cout << "(1) ADD ELEMENT LIST1." << endl;
        cout << "(2) PRINT LIST1" << endl;
        cout << "(3) ADD ELEMENT LIST2" << endl;
        cout << "(4) PRINT LIST2" << endl;
        cout << "(5) PRINT BOTH LISTS" << endl;
    cout << "(6) USE MERGE FUNCTION" << endl;
        cout << "(7) TO EXIT" << endl;

        cin >> menuOption;
        system ("cls");
    };


    void dragons()
    {

        node *temp1 = startList1;
        node *temp2 = startList2;
        while(temp1)
        {
            temp1 = startList1->next;
            delete startList1;
            startList1=temp1;
        }
        while(temp2)
        {
            temp2 = startList2->next;
            delete startList2;
            startList2=temp2;
        }
    };      

};

int main()
{
    struct node *p = NULL, *q = NULL;

    list s;
    s.printMenu();
    node* list1;
    node* list2;
    node* sorting;
    while(s.menuOption!=7)
    {
        switch (s.menuOption)
        {
            case 1: s.addList1(list1);
                    break;
            case 2: s.printList1(list1);
                    break;
            case 3: s.addList2(list2);
                    break;
            case 4: s.printList2(list2);
                    break;
            case 5:s.printBoth(list1, list2);
                    break;
            case 6:s.merge();
                    break;
            default: cout << "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!!!!" << endl;
                    break;
        }
        system ("pause");
        system ("cls");
        s.printMenu();
    }
    s.dragons();
    return 0;
}
```

So now user can input elements to both lists and see them, but how can i create a function, that will merge those lists without duplicate values? for example:
List1 = 1, 2, 3, 6, 8;
List2 = 2, 4, 5, 7, 8;

Merged list = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8; (can be whatever order actually, it doesn't matter)

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What good is a linked list if you can't retrieve the data from it?  Note that your entire `struct list` has no way to get the data added to it from `main` or able to iterate from beginning to end from `main`.  That would be the first step in getting a `merge()` to work properly.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to c++ language and i don't quite understand what are you talking about. What should i do to "get the data added to it from main or able to iterate from beginning to end from main"?

Comment: You built a linked list class, and there is no way to read the data from those lists from outside the `list` struct.  Second, your `addList1` and `addList2` functions do not change the passed-in parameter.  You're sending uninitialized pointers to `addList1` and `addList2`, and they will remain uninitialized on return of those functions. If you want proof, set `list1` and `list2` to `nullptr` before calling your `add...()` functions.  You will see that they are still `nullptr` after those functions are called.  So your entire `main` has bugs whenever you use `list1` and `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your code, but using an STL list container to provide the linked list, and this provides its own functions that will achieve what you want. This code is for demonstration, and is not optimised for efficiency, it just shows one possible method of merging unique elements from two lists. (For this to work, the list requires its elements to be sorted, and you need to provide predicates for "less than" and "equal to" for the nodes in the list.) 
(Its true that it takes time to learn some of the STL containers and functions, but many people would recommend doing that instead of trying to create your own raw-pointer-based linked list from scratch.)

Hope this helps, or is of interest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>

struct node
{
    int info;
    node (int i)
    {
        info = i;
    }
    ~node()
    {
        //std::cout <<"NODE CONTAINING \"" << info << "\" WAS DELETED!" << std::endl;
    }
};

bool nodeLess(node n1, node n2)
{
    return n1.info < n2.info;
}

bool nodeEqual(node n1, node n2)
{
    return n1.info == n2.info;
}

struct mylist
{
    int menuOption;

    std::list<node> list1;
    std::list<node> list2;

    void addList(std::list<node>& l)
    {
        int x;
        std::cout << "PLEASE INPUT VALUE WHICH YOU WANT IN THE NODE: ";
        std::cin >> x;
        node n(x);
        l.push_back(n);
    }

    void printList(const std::list<node>& l)
    {
        for (std::list<node>::const_iterator it = l.cbegin(); it != l.cend(); ++it)
        {
            std::cout << it->info << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void addList1()  { addList(list1); }
    void addList2()  { addList(list2); }

    void printList1() { printList(list1); }
    void printList2() { printList(list2); }

    // this just prints first and second lists to show what is inside..
    void printBoth()
    {
        std::cout << "Elements of the first list:" << std::endl;
        printList1();
        std::cout << "Elements of the second list:" << std::endl;
        printList2();
    }

    void simpleMerge()
    {
        std::list<node> merged;
        merged.insert(merged.end(), list1.begin(), list1.end());
        merged.insert(merged.end(), list2.begin(), list2.end());
        std::cout << "CONTENTS OF LIST1 THEN LIST2: " << std::endl;
        printList(merged);
    }

    void uniqueSortMerge()
    {
        std::list<node> sorted1(list1.begin(), list1.end());
        std::list<node> sorted2(list2.begin(), list2.end());
        sorted1.sort(nodeLess);
        sorted2.sort(nodeLess);
        sorted1.unique(nodeEqual);
        sorted2.unique(nodeEqual);
        std::list<node> merged;
        std::merge(sorted1.begin(), sorted1.end(),
                   sorted2.begin(), sorted2.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(merged),
                   nodeLess);
        std::cout << "UNIQUE CONTENTS OF LIST1 AND LIST2 SORTED AND MERGED: " << std::endl;
        printList(merged);
    }

    void printMenu()
    {
        std::cout << "MENU" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(1) ADD ELEMENT LIST1." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(2) PRINT LIST1" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(3) ADD ELEMENT LIST2" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(4) PRINT LIST2" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(5) PRINT BOTH LISTS" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(6) USE SIMPLE MERGE FUNCTION" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(7) USE UNIQUE, SORT AND MERGE FUNCTION" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "(8) TO EXIT" << std::endl;

        std::cin >> menuOption;
        system ("cls");
    };


    void dragons()
    {
        list1.clear();
        list2.clear();
    };
};

int main()
{
    mylist s;

    do
    {
        s.printMenu();
        switch (s.menuOption)
        {
            case 1:
                s.addList1();
                break;
            case 2:
                s.printList1();
                break;
            case 3:
                s.addList2();
                break;
            case 4:
                s.printList2();
                break;
            case 5:
                s.printBoth();
                break;
            case 6:
                s.simpleMerge();
                break;
            case 7:
                s.uniqueSortMerge();
                break;
            case 8:
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!!!!" << std::endl;
                break;
        }
        system ("pause");
        system ("cls");
    } while(s.menuOption != 8);

    s.dragons();
    return 0;
}
```